# rosidl_runtime_c/message_type_support_struct.h error

Tags: ros, ros2, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm getting myself into troubles again and would kindly ask for some insight into where I'm messing up.

I have been trying to add a simple publisher for the TFMini_Plus sensor data on my teensy 4.1
Using micro-ROS and platformIO on Ubuntu 22.04.1

The following line of code:

```
RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(&publisher_range, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(sesnsor_msgs, msg, Range), "micro_ros_platformio_node_publisher_range"));
```

generates this error when compiling:

```
src/main.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
.pio/libdeps/teensy41/micro_ros_platformio/libmicroros/include/rosidl_runtime_c/message_type_support_struct.h:78:59: error: 'rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type_support_handle__sesnsor_msgs__msg__Range' was not declared in this scope
     rosidl_typesupport_c, PkgName, MsgSubfolder, MsgName)()
                                                           ^
src/main.cpp:107:43: note: in definition of macro 'RCCHECK'
 #define RCCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){error_loop();}}
                                           ^
src/main.cpp:330:64: note: in expansion of macro 'ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT'
   RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(&publisher_range, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(sesnsor_msgs, msg, Range), "micro_ros_platformio_node_publisher_range"));
```

upon checking the .pio directory structure, I can clearly identify the appropriate directories and files, just as with all other message types.

Here a partial of the directory structure of .pio

```
.pio
├── bin
└── libdeps
    └── teensy41
        └── micro_ros_platformio
            ├── libmicroros
            │   ├── include
            │   │   ├── sensor_msgs
            │   │   │   ├── msg
            │   │   │   │   ├── battery_state.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── camera_info.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── channel_float32.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── compressed_image.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── detail
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── battery_state__functions.c
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── battery_state__functions.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── ...
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__functions.c
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__functions.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__rosidl_typesupport_microxrcedds_c.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__struct.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__type_support.c
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── range__type_support.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── region_of_interest__functions.c
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── region_of_interest__functions.h
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── ...
            │   │   │   │   ├── fluid_pressure.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── ...
            │   │   │   │   ├── range.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── region_of_interest.h
            │   │   │   │   ├── ...
            │   │   │   └── srv
            │   │   │       ├── detail
```

It is unclear to me why the sensor_msgs/Range fails to properly integrate.
Am I forgetting to "register" the sensor messages somehow?

I do have the `#include <sensor_msgs/msg/range.h>` in the top of my source code.

Here the entire source code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <micro_ros_platformio.h>
#include <example_interfaces/srv/add_two_ints.h>
#include <example_interfaces/srv/set_bool.h>
#include <teensy_interfaces/srv/neo_pixel_control.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <global.h>
#include <config.h>
#include <setup.h>
#include <rcl/error_handling.h>
#include <rcl/rcl.h>
#include <rclc/rclc.h>
#include <rclc/executor.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/int32.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/int64.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/bool.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/range.h>
#include <WS2812Serial.h>

#if !defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_ARDUINO_SERIAL)
#error This example is only avaliable for Arduino framework with serial transport.
#endif

volatile int TFMiniVal = 0;
volatile int TFMiniStrength = 0;
int TFMini_FloorDistance = 30;
int TFMini_FloorDistanceTolerance = 12;

// ============================================================================
// INSTANCES, OBJECTS
// ============================================================================
// publisher and subscriber common
rcl_node_t node;
rclc_support_t support;
rcl_allocator_t allocator;
rclc_executor_t executor;
rcl_timer_t timer;
unsigned int num_handles = 7;   // 1 subscribers, 2 publishers, 4 services

// service addTwoInts
// rcl_service_t service_addTwoInts;

// services
rcl_service_t service_FrontLights;
rcl_service_t service_RearLights;
rcl_service_t service_OdriveFans;
rcl_service_t service_NeoPixel;

rcl_wait_set_t wait_set;

// msg_pub publisher
rcl_publisher_t publisher;
std_msgs__msg__Int32 msg_pub;

// msg_pub_range publisher
rcl_publisher_t publisher_range;
sensor_msgs__msg__Range msg_pub_range;

// subscriber
rcl_subscription_t subscriber;
std_msgs__msg__Int32 msg_sub;

// example_interfaces__srv__AddTwoInts_Response res;
// example_interfaces__srv__AddTwoInts_Request req;

example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request  req_FrontLights;
example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response res_FrontLights;

example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request  req_RearLights;
example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response res_RearLights;

example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request  req_OdriveFans;
example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response res_OdriveFans;

teensy_interfaces__srv__NeoPixelControl_Request  req_NeoPixel;
teensy_interfaces__srv__NeoPixelControl_Response res_NeoPixel;

// Left NeoPixel
byte dwgMem_NeoPixel_L[numNeoPixel_L*3];         //  3 bytes per LED
DMAMEM byte dispMem_NeoPixel_L[numNeoPixel_L*12]; // 12 bytes per LED
WS2812Serial objNeoPixel_L(numNeoPixel_L, dispMem_NeoPixel_L, dwgMem_NeoPixel_L, pinNeoPixel_L, WS2812_GRB);

// Right NeoPixel
byte dwgMem_NeoPixel_R[numNeoPixel_R*3];         //  3 bytes per LED
DMAMEM byte dispMem_NeoPixel_R[numNeoPixel_R*12]; // 12 bytes per LED
WS2812Serial objNeoPixel_R(numNeoPixel_R, dispMem_NeoPixel_R, dwgMem_NeoPixel_R, pinNeoPixel_R, WS2812_GRB);

// ============================================================================
// DEFINES
// ============================================================================
// I/O - Definitions
#define LED_PIN 13

// cleartext substitutions
// debug
#ifndef DebugMonitor
#define DebugMonitor Serial6
#endif

#define debug(x) DebugMonitor.print(x)
#define debugln(x) DebugMonitor.println(x)

// ============================================================================
// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
// ============================================================================
#define RCCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){error_loop();}}
#define RCSOFTCHECK(fn) {rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){}}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// NeoPixel.colorWipe
void colorWipe(int, int, WS2812Serial);

// TFMini-Plus
void readTFMiniPlus(void);

// Error handle loop
void error_loop() {
  while(1) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN));
    delay(500);
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// timer callback (currently just increments msg_pub.data)
void timer_callback(rcl_timer_t * timer, int64_t last_call_time) {
  RCLC_UNUSED(last_call_time);
  if (timer != NULL) {
    // increments msg_pub.data and publishes on the topic
    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&publisher, &msg_pub, NULL));
    msg_pub.data++;

    // publishes the latest value from TFMini-Plus
    msg_pub_range.range = TFMiniVal;
    msg_pub_range.min_range = 0;
    msg_pub_range.max_range = 1000;
    msg_pub_range.radiation_type = sensor_msgs__msg__Range__INFRARED;
    msg_pub_range.field_of_view = 0.04;
    msg_pub_range.header.frame_id.data = "TFMini-Plus"; 

    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&publisher, &msg_pub_range, NULL));
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// subscriber callback
void subscription_callback(const void * msgin) {  
  const std_msgs__msg__Int32 * msg = (const std_msgs__msg__Int32 *)msgin;
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, (msg->data == 0) ? LOW : HIGH);  
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// srv.addTwoInts callback
// void service_addTwoInts_callback(const void * req, void * res) {
//   example_interfaces__srv__AddTwoInts_Request * req_in = (example_interfaces__srv__AddTwoInts_Request *) req;
//   example_interfaces__srv__AddTwoInts_Response * res_in = (example_interfaces__srv__AddTwoInts_Response *) res;

//   //printf("Service request value: %d + %d.\n", (int) req_in->a, (int) req_in->b);

//   res_in->sum = req_in->a + req_in->b;
// }
// --------------------------------------------------------
// srv.FrontLights callback
void service_FrontLights_callback(const void * req_FrontLights, void * res_FrontLights) {
  bool previousState = digitalRead(FRONT_LIGHT);
  example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request * req_in = (example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request *) req_FrontLights;
  example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response * res_in = (example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response *) res_FrontLights;
  
  digitalWrite(FRONT_LIGHT, (req_in->data == 0) ? LOW:HIGH);

  if (previousState != digitalRead(FRONT_LIGHT)) {
    res_in->success = true;
    res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Front Lights succeeded to update");
  }
  else {
    res_in->success = false;
    res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Front Lights FAILED to update");
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// srv.RearLights callback
void service_RearLights_callback(const void * req_RearLights, void * res_RearLights) {
  bool previousState = digitalRead(REAR_LIGHT);
  example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request * req_in = (example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request *) req_RearLights;
  example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response * res_in = (example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response *) res_RearLights;
  
  digitalWrite(REAR_LIGHT, (req_in->data == 0) ? LOW:HIGH);

  if (previousState != digitalRead(REAR_LIGHT)) {
    res_in->success = true;
    res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Rear Lights succeeded to update");
  }
  else {
    res_in->success = false;
    res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Rear Lights FAILED to update");
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// srv.OdriveFans callback
void service_OdriveFans_callback(const void * req_OdriveFans, void * res_OdriveFans) {
  bool previousState = digitalRead(ODRIVE_FAN);
  example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request * req_in = (example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Request *) req_OdriveFans;
  example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response * res_in = (example_interfaces__srv__SetBool_Response *) res_OdriveFans;
  
  digitalWrite(ODRIVE_FAN, (req_in->data == 0) ? LOW:HIGH);

  if (previousState != digitalRead(ODRIVE_FAN)) {
    res_in->success = true;
    res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Odrive Fans succeeded to update");
  }
  else {
    res_in->success = false;
    res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Odrive Fans FAILED to update");
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// srv.NeoPixel callback
void service_NeoPixel_callback(const void * req_NeoPixel, void * res_NeoPixel) {
  teensy_interfaces__srv__NeoPixelControl_Request * req_in = (teensy_interfaces__srv__NeoPixelControl_Request *) req_NeoPixel;
  teensy_interfaces__srv__NeoPixelControl_Response * res_in = (teensy_interfaces__srv__NeoPixelControl_Response *) res_NeoPixel;
  
  switch(req_in->status) {
    case 1:
      colorWipe(ORANGE, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(ORANGE, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 2:
      colorWipe(RED, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(RED, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 3:
      colorWipe(GREEN, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(GREEN, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 4:
      colorWipe(BLUE, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(BLUE, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 5:
      colorWipe(YELLOW, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(YELLOW, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 6:
      colorWipe(PINK, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(PINK, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 7:
      colorWipe(ORANGE, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(ORANGE, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    case 8:
      colorWipe(WHT, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(WHT, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
    default:
      colorWipe(BLANK, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
      colorWipe(BLANK, 10, objNeoPixel_R);
      break;
  }
  res_in->success = true;
  res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Neopixel changed");
  
  // res_in->success = true;
  // res_in->message.data = const_cast<char*>("Neopixel blanked");
}

// ============================================================================
// SETUP
// ============================================================================
void setup() {
  set_microros_serial_transports(Serial);

  // Debug
  DebugMonitor.begin(115200);
  
  // I/O setup
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); 

  pinMode(FRONT_LIGHT, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(FRONT_LIGHT, LOW);
  pinMode(REAR_LIGHT, OUTPUT);  digitalWrite(REAR_LIGHT, LOW);
  pinMode(ODRIVE_FAN, OUTPUT);  digitalWrite(ODRIVE_FAN, LOW);

  // Neopixel
  objNeoPixel_L.begin();
  objNeoPixel_R.begin();

  // TFMini Plus
  TFMiniPlus.begin(115200);  // HW Serial for TFmini
  delay (200);            // Give a little time for things to start
  // Set TFMini Plus to Standard Output mode
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x42);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x57);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x02);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x00);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x00);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x00);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x01);
  TFMiniPlus.write(0x06);

  delay(1000);
  colorWipe(ORANGE, 10, objNeoPixel_L);
  colorWipe(ORANGE, 10, objNeoPixel_R);

  allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();

  // create init_options
  RCCHECK(rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator));

  // create node
  RCCHECK(rclc_node_init_default(&node, "uros_platformio_node", "", &support));

  // create service addTwoInts
  // RCCHECK(rclc_service_init_default(&service_addTwoInts, &node, ROSIDL_GET_SRV_TYPE_SUPPORT(example_interfaces, srv, AddTwoInts), "/addtwoints"));

  // create service FrontLights
  RCCHECK(rclc_service_init_default(&service_FrontLights, &node, ROSIDL_GET_SRV_TYPE_SUPPORT(example_interfaces, srv, SetBool), "/frontlights"));

  // create service RearLights
  RCCHECK(rclc_service_init_default(&service_RearLights, &node, ROSIDL_GET_SRV_TYPE_SUPPORT(example_interfaces, srv, SetBool), "/rearlights"));

  // create service OdriveFans
  RCCHECK(rclc_service_init_default(&service_OdriveFans, &node, ROSIDL_GET_SRV_TYPE_SUPPORT(example_interfaces, srv, SetBool), "/odrivefans"));

  // create service NeoPixel
  RCCHECK(rclc_service_init_default(&service_NeoPixel, &node, ROSIDL_GET_SRV_TYPE_SUPPORT(teensy_interfaces, srv, NeoPixelControl), "/neopixel"));
    
  // create msg_pub publisher
  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(&publisher, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int32), "micro_ros_platformio_node_publisher"));

  // create msg_pub_range publisher
  // RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(&publisher_range, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int32), "micro_ros_platformio_node_publisher_range"));
  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(&publisher_range, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(sesnsor_msgs, msg, Range), "micro_ros_platformio_node_publisher_range"));

  // create subscriber
  RCCHECK(rclc_subscription_init_default(&subscriber, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int32), "micro_ros_platformio_node_subscriber"));

  // create timer,
  const unsigned int timer_timeout = 1000;
  RCCHECK(rclc_timer_init_default(&timer, &support, RCL_MS_TO_NS(timer_timeout), timer_callback));

  // create executor
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, num_handles, &allocator));  
  // RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_service(&executor, &service_addTwoInts, &req, &res, service_addTwoInts_callback));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_service(&executor, &service_FrontLights, &req_FrontLights, &res_FrontLights, service_FrontLights_callback));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_service(&executor, &service_RearLights, &req_RearLights, &res_RearLights, service_RearLights_callback));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_service(&executor, &service_OdriveFans, &req_OdriveFans, &res_OdriveFans, service_OdriveFans_callback));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_service(&executor, &service_NeoPixel, &req_NeoPixel, &res_NeoPixel, service_NeoPixel_callback));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_subscription(&executor, &subscriber, &msg_sub, &subscription_callback, ON_NEW_DATA));   
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_timer(&executor, &timer));

  msg_pub.data = 0;
} // end setup

// ============================================================================
// MAIN LOOP
// ============================================================================
void loop() {
  // variable declarations
  uint32_t t = millis();

  if (bFirstScan) {
    bFirstScan = false;
    debugln("First Scan");
  }  

  // ------------------------------------------------------
  // Service Routine[0]: DEBUG
  #if SR00_DEBUG_EN == 1
  if ((t-tTime[0]) >= (1000 / DEBUG_PULSE))
  {
    debugln(msg_pub.data);
    tTime[0] = t;
  }
  #endif

  #if SR01_TFMINI_EN == 1
  if ((t-tTime[1]) >= (1000 / TFM_PULSE))
  {
    readTFMiniPlus();
    debug("Distance: "); debugln(TFMiniVal);
    debug("Strength: "); debugln(TFMiniStrength);
    debugln("--------------------");
    tTime[1] = t;
  }
  #endif




  // EXECUTOR HANDLE SPIN
  if ((t-tTime[10]) >= (1000 / SPIN_PULSE))
  {
    RCSOFTCHECK(rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor, RCL_MS_TO_NS(100)));
    tTime[10] = t;
  }  
}

// --------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTIONS
// --------------------------------------------------------
// colorWipe
void colorWipe(int color, int wait, WS2812Serial refObject) {
  for (int i=0; i < refObject.numPixels(); i++) {
    refObject.setPixel(i, color);
    refObject.show();
    delayMicroseconds(wait);
  }
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void readTFMiniPlus(){
// Data Format for Benewake TFmini
// ===============================
// 9 bytes total per message:
// 1) 0x59
// 2) 0x59
// 3) Dist_L (low 8bit)
// 4) Dist_H (high 8bit)
// 5) Strength_L (low 8bit)
// 6) Strength_H (high 8bit)
// 7) Reserved bytes
// 8) Original signal quality degree
// 9) Checksum parity bit (low 8bit), Checksum = Byte1 + Byte2 +…+Byte8. This is only a low 8bit though
while(TFMiniPlus.available()>=9) // When at least 9 bytes of data available (expected number of bytes for 1 signal), then read
{
  // debugln("Check2");
  if((0x59 == TFMiniPlus.read()) && (0x59 == TFMiniPlus.read())) // byte 1 and byte 2
  {
    unsigned int t1 = TFMiniPlus.read(); // byte 3 = Dist_L
    unsigned int t2 = TFMiniPlus.read(); // byte 4 = Dist_H
    t2 <<= 8;
    t2 += t1;
    TFMiniVal = t2*10;
    t1 = TFMiniPlus.read(); // byte 5 = Strength_L
    t2 = TFMiniPlus.read(); // byte 6 = Strength_H
    t2 <<= 8;
    t2 += t1;
    TFMiniStrength = t2;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)TFMiniPlus.read(); // byte 7, 8, 9 are ignored
  }
}
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408720/rosidl_runtime_c/message_type_support_struct.h-error/) by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2022-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The following line of code:
>
> ```
> RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(&publisher_range, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(sesnsor_msgs, msg, Range), "micro_ros_platformio_node_publisher_range"));
> ```
>
> generates this error when compiling:
>
> ```
> [..]
> error: 'rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type_support_handle__sesnsor_msgs__msg__Range' was not declared in this scope
> ```

isn't this just a typo?

You have `sesnsor_msgs` (note the extra `s`).

The correct name of the package would be `sensor_msgs`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) on 2022-10-31**:
Of course you're right @gvdhoorn
I have been staring at the screen for too long.
The number of "speeling" mistakes my acute keyboard dyslexia causes, I should know better to check twice.
Apologies for wasting your time :-)
I hardly doubt it took you more than 5s, but still..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-31**:
You don't need to apologise for anything, and no time was wasted. Happens to all of us.